# EF Core many-to-many insert : how to nicely avoid EF trying to add an already existing unique-constraint sub-entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

Good evening :-)

I have a question I cannot answer regarding a many-to-many INSERT case with EFCore.

I have a `Recipe` that has many `Tag`. A `Tag` (take "dinner" for example) can be in many `Recipe`. Both have their SQL table.

To make this many-to-many work, I also have a joining SQL table and its associated object `RecipeTag`.

*Note #1 : classes code is at the end of this post*

*Note #2 : every GET/SELECT operation works like a charm, many-to-many is implemented and works*

To take a simple example, starting from fresh empty tables, I post my new `Recipe` :

```
POST /recipes
{
  "title": "A first title",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "dinner"
    }
  ]
}
```

That goes well. I see my new entries in `Recipe` table, `Tag` table, and `RecipeTag` table linking both `id`.

Now, I register a new `Recipe` again, with the **same** `Tag`:

```
POST /recipes
{
  "title": "A second title",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "dinner"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I got a UNIQUE key constraint violation from EF Core. It will try to register a new `Tag` with the name `dinner`. It's actually quite normal to exception since I've put a unique constraint into `Tag`.`tagnam` field.

***Question :*** is there a nice way to get around this ? Meaning, to have EF Core registering the second `Recipe` and the joining `RecipeTag` entity as well, recognizing the `Tag` itself exists, not by the PK only this time, but by the unique constraint.

It seems (and it's logic) EF Core won't try to add an entity if it sees the `id` (PK) is already in db. But in my case : I would want EF Core to check unique constraint as well, and if it conflicts, take the `id` of conflicting entity in db and lazy-put-it in my `Tag` object so it can (just after) insert properly the `RecipeTag` joining entity with correct `id` !

Sorry, it's a bit messy ...

The only "not-so-bad" solution I have for now :

1. API controller receives the `RecipeDto`
2. we extract the tags from this new recipe as `string[]`
3. we extract **existing tags** from db matching the ones we would want to add
4. when tranforming `RecipeDto` to `Recipe`, the field (see below) `ICollection<RecipeTag>` will contain proper `Tag` with `id` set for existing ones, and some no-id `Tag` objects, for the ones we truly need to add
5. as already stated, EF Core will recognize some `Tag` have an id filled and won't try to insert them in db - it will just insert the ones without an id

Classes I use :

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Recipe that can contain many tags
/// </summary>
[Table("rcp")]
public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("rcptit")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecipeTag> RecipeTags { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Tag contained into many recipes
/// </summary>
[Table("tag")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("tagnam")] // this has a UNIQUE constraint in db to avoid having 2 times the same tag
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Join table between Recipes and Tags
/// </summary>
[Table("rcptag")]
public class RecipeTag
{
    [Column("rcpid")]
    public Guid RecipeId { get; set; }

    [Column("tagid")]
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }

    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeTag> RecipeTags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp");

        builder.Entity<Tag>().HasIndex(e => e.Name).IsUnique();
        // composite primary key for RecipeTag
        builder.Entity<RecipeTag>().HasKey(rt => new { rt.RecipeId, rt.TagId });
        builder.Entity<RecipeTag>().HasOne(rt => rt.Recipe).WithMany(r => r.RecipeTags).HasForeignKey(rt => rt.RecipeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried also to have just Tag.Name in the class, as PrimaryKey (so, no more Unique constraint stuff), and it does not work ! Same problems of unique key (since PK is ... in fact a sort of unique key ^^), but now on the PK Tag.name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing one side of the Many to Many setup in your configuration, which might be causing the problem. Try switching the setup as follows. Delete

```cs
builder.Entity<RecipeTag>().HasOne(rt => rt.Recipe).WithMany(r => r.RecipeTags).HasForeignKey(rt => rt.RecipeId);
```

and then add

```cs
builder.Entity<RecipeTag>().HasOne(rt => rt.Tag).WithMany(r => r.RecipeTags).HasForeignKey(rt => rt.TagId).IsRequired();
builder.Entity<RecipeTag>().HasOne(rt => rt.Recipe).WithMany(r => r.RecipeTags).HasForeignKey(rt => rt.RecipeId).IsRequired();
```

This defines the relationship for both sides of the composite key.

Comment: I though as well but it's not because of that. In fact the other way is not interesting for what I intend to do.